# Importing models from a different Django project

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am setting up a public API for my app. I want to segregate my API code from my application code, so I am putting it in a new django project and am using "Django REST Framework" to build the scaffolding for the public API services.

I'm struggling with how to keep models in sync between my main application project, and this new Django project for the API... product development may continue in the application project that necessitates models changes, and I'd like those models changes to be propagated to the API project.

Is there a way to point to, or import, models from a different Django project?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't there be security issues at letting an external site dictate what your db's structure looks like? A problem of any kind (or a man in the middle attack) could completely modify (or destroy) your database without you doing anything.

I'd say it's better to have API versions than what you're asking for. I'd prefer to have 2 concurrent versions running at the same time, to let the time for the API consumers to update their schemas, than force automatic updates of their schemas and data. And in general, if possible, I'd only use a single API version, taking care to always keep a compatibility with older implementations.

But I'm just saying that for general public API, I don't know how open your API should be and how close your developpements (API and consumer) are, so I may be completely out of your scope!

Comment: I do not think there is a a security concern: Im having my application code and api code on separate infrastructures that can scale independently, but i want to wire them up with the same models...

Comment: So I would probably package the model in an app used by both projects, allowing you to have a single modification point (that app) which propagates to both projects (but I've never had to do it, so I don't know much about it). Also, even if I'm ashamed for not doing that for every project, I think that developping an API is the typically the best use case for `TDD` as the tests you would write for this would exactly be what your API consumer is waiting for.